# How to remove warning in UIImage-Categories 3.party

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

Now, I have a problem with UIImage-Categories 3.party. 
It is warning:

`Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class`
[image]

Could you have and ideas or solutions for solving the problem. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: rename the method? its interfering with an existing method name. if you want the functionality of the class you are creating the category for as well, you probably want to extend the class and not make a category

Comment: i think so this method is already present in primary class of which u made the category.Rename the method

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create method that already defined into `UIImage` class.
The simplest solution is to rename method, but it will make some pain to place everywhere your extended method.
If you want to save the same name of method I recommend you to perform Swizzling.